# Quantity of elements of order $d$ in $Z_n$, with $d \mid n $

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, gcd-and-lcm

I'm studying for an exam and I can't answer this problem. I'd appreciate a hint.

What I've got so far:

Let $x$ be an element or order $d$. Then, $x\cdot d \equiv 0 \pmod n \Rightarrow n \mid x\cdot d$.

And, on the other hand, obviously $n \mid d\ .\ n$

$n$ divides each factor $\Rightarrow  n\mid \gcd(x\cdot d,d\cdot n)\ =\ d\cdot \gcd(x,n) \Rightarrow \frac{n}{d} \mid \gcd(x,n)$

My guess is that there are at most two elements (if they are different mod $n$): $\pm \frac{n}{d}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G=Z_n$, and by Fundamental theorem of cyclic groups, there exists unique subgroup of order $d$ in $G$, if $d\mid n$, call it $H=\langle a\rangle$. Now every element of order $d$ must generate $H$, and how many generators does $\langle a \rangle$ have? You must have done it, right?

Generators of $\langle a\rangle$ are elements of the form $a^k$ where gcd$(k,n)=1$. This number is called [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) denoted by $\phi(n)=\{k\in Z : 1\le k \le n,  (k,n)=1 \}$. So number of elements of order $d$ in $G=Z_n$ is $\phi(n)$

Comment: I didn't know that theorem! Cool. Well, $a^k$ is a generator iff $k$ is coprime with $d$, so $\phi(d)$ = #generators of $<a>$. And it's obvious that if an element generates $H$, then it had order $d$.

I guess my intuition that there were at most two elements was wrong.

Comment: You have messed up notations in your argument. Its better to write groups multiplicatively rather then additivly. Anyways, by your notation, $x.d=x.n=0$, so obviously $n$ divides 0 and also if $n|d.n$ doesn't have to imply $n|gcd(x.d,d.n)$. Take $x=5, d=5, n=10$

Comment: Oh, but I'm using that $n | x \cdot d$ and that $n | d\cdot n$ to imply that $n | gcd(x\cdot d, d\cdot n)$. That's a fundamental law of $gcd$: if $m | a$ and $m | b$ then $m | gcd(a,b)$. I'll edit my post to clarify it.
About notation, $Z_n$ is commutative, so I prefer to write it additivly (also, in $Z_n$ the operation **is** to sum). Why do you say that it's better to write groups multiplicatively?

Comment: Abelian groups(which includes cyclic ones) are usually written in additive notation actually but this is pretty much reserved for abelian groups. Never use addition to denote a non commutative operation but you can use multiplication to denote a commutative operation. So multiplication is used more generally than addition.

Comment: I think the answer is $\phi(d)$ and there is a typo in last line.